# Renaming Child Nodes where there are two of the same

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am trying to rename one of the child nodes where two exist within a parent node and create a new XML file with the updated information.There may be a parent node `<Accounts>` with one child node, but where there exist a 2nd child node with the same name, I'd like to rename it, to something like `<Account2></Account2>`. I have some code where I read the entire XML file and renames the node, but I know this is not the right approach.

For example XML data looks similar to the below:

```xml
<Accounts>
    <Account>Value</Account>
    <Account>Value</Account>
</Accounts>
```

VBScript:

```vb
Dim objFSO, objTextFile, strText, strNewText, objNewFile
Dim strOriginalFile, strTempFile

strOriginalFile = "c:\XML_File.xml"

strTempFile = "c:\temp.xml"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objNewFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strTempFile)

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strOriginalFile, 1)
strText = objTextFile.ReadAll

strNewText = Replace(strText, "<Account>", "<Account2>", vbTextCompare)

objNewFile.Write strNewText

objTextFile.Close
objNewFile.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) notation, you can access child nodes based off context.  Loops through each `<Account>` child node, replaces it with an enumerated node that's a deep copy of the old one.

```vbs
Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xml.async = False
count_var = 1

If xml.Load("C:\file.xml") Then
    For Each accountCollection In xml.SelectNodes("//Accounts")
        For Each account In accountCollection.SelectNodes("./Account")
            If count_var > 1 Then

                Set accountEnum = xml.createNode(1, "Account" & count_var, "")
                For Each child In account.childNodes
                    accountEnum.appendChild(child.cloneNode(TRUE))
                Next
                accountCollection.replaceChild accountEnum, account

                xml.save("C:\file.xml")
            End If
            count_var = count_var + 1
        Next
        count_var = 1
    Next
End If
```

**Input:**

```xml
<Accounts>
    <Account>test</Account>
    <Account>
        <ID>000</ID>
        <CONFIG type="binary" name="test"/>
    </Account>
    <Account>test1</Account>
</Accounts>
```

**Output**

```
<Accounts>
    <Account>test</Account>
    <Account2>
        <ID>000</ID>
        <CONFIG type="binary" name="test"/>
    </Account2>
    <Account3>test1</Account3>
</Accounts>
```

Comment: Definitely something I can work with and learn from. Unfortunately, it renamed the 2nd Childs opening node to <Account2/> and closing child node to </Account> , when it should be <Account2>and </Account2>. It also deleted everything between the child nodes as well. Really do appreciate the effort.

Comment: Maybe to fix the closing child node I can just re-run the script twice.

Comment: That's why I have the comment in there, you're going to have to copy attributes/text of the node you're replacing. `<Account2/>` represents a standalone node with no attributes or text assigned.

Comment: Could you show me a quick example on how to copy the additional nodes and values between <Account2><OtherNode>Values</OtherNode></Account2>. Much Appreciated!

Comment: You can clone the child nodes and reattach them to the new node. Check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757828(v=vs.85).aspx) : On mobile right now, but if I get a chance I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Will definitely take a look - Thanks.

Comment: @FabeDole - Not sure if you were able to figure it out, but take a look at the edited code as well as I/O

Comment: Works great. This is really good work. I think what you have done is going to allow me to build on. Thanks for your help. You have sent me in the right direction. Thanks and very much appreciative!

Comment: I was trying to build based on what you did for me and seems that I am getting stuck. Was hoping if you could shed some light. Link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258601/trying-to-add-a-node-in-vbscript?noredirect=1#comment73626274_43258601]