# Trying to add a node in VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have some code that renames the child nodes (HolderAccount) to HolderAccount1 and HolderAccount2. Some HolderAccounts may have one or two HolderAccount child nodes. I want to create a new HolderAccount, where there is only one HolderAccount in HolderAccounts.

Parent Node = HolderAccounts
Child Node  = HolderAccount

Input Sample:

```xml
<HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccount>test</HolderAccount>        
</HolderAccounts>

<HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccount>test</HolderAccount>
    <HolderAccount>test</HolderAccount>
</HolderAccounts>
```

My Output:

```xml
<HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccount1>test</HolderAccount1>
    <HolderAccount2/> 
</HolderAccounts>

<HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccount1>test</HolderAccount1> 
    <HolderAccount2>test</HolderAccount2>
    <HolderAccount2/>       
</HolderAccounts>
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

```xml
<HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccount1>test</HolderAccount1>
    <HolderAccount2></HolderAccount2> 
</HolderAccounts>

<HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccount1>test</HolderAccount1> 
    <HolderAccount2>test</HolderAccount2>                      
</HolderAccounts>
```

```vb
Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = False
count_var = 1

total_accounts = 0
total_modified_accounts = 0

'Get data from directory 
If xml.Load("c:\XML_DATA2.xml") Then
    'Find and give me a list of all HolderAccounts 
    For Each HolderAccounts In xml.SelectNodes("//HolderAccounts")
        'Find and give me a list of all HolderAccount    
        For Each HolderAccount In HolderAccounts.SelectNodes("./HolderAccount")
            'Check to see if you are pointing to 2nd HolderAccount in the HolderAccounts
            If count_var > 1 Then
                'Rename the 2nd HolderAccount in HolderAccounts
                Set accountEnum = xml.createNode(1, "HolderAccount" & count_var, "")

                'Give me the current nodes child nodes 
                For Each child In HolderAccount.childNodes
                    'Attach the child nodes to the account
                    accountEnum.appendChild(child.cloneNode(True))
                Next
                HolderAccounts.replaceChild accountEnum, HolderAccount

                total_modified_accounts = total_modified_accounts + 1
                xml.Save("c:\XML_DATA2.xml")
            Else    '1st HolderAccount 
                'Rename the 1st account 
                Set accountEnum = xml.createNode(1, "HolderAccount" & count_var, "")

                For Each child In HolderAccount.childNodes
                    accountEnum.appendChild(child.cloneNode(TRUE))
                Next
                HolderAccounts.replaceChild accountEnum, HolderAccount 

                'This is returning <HolderAccount2/> for nodes within <HolderAccounts>, 
                'I only want to create a new node where exist one node within <HolderAccounts>
                Set accountEnum2 = xml.createElement("HolderAccount2")
                HolderAccounts.appendChild(accountEnum2)

                xml.Save("c:\XML_DATA2.xml")
            End If
            count_var = count_var + 1
        Next           
        count_var = 1
        total_accounts = 0      
    Next
End If

Set node = Nothing
Set xml  = Nothing
```

Comment: Numbered node names are a flawed approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve here IMO. If for some obscure reason you absolutely must attach an index to the nodes, just add an index attribute to them.

Comment: Create new element node and attach new empty text node.

Comment: @Ansgar - What would be your approach then ? And why would this be a flawed approach ? Curious ... Thanks for responding!

Comment: An account is an account is an account. Nodes containing the same type of data should have the same node name to reflect this. My actual take on this wuold depend heavily on what actual problem you're trying to solve with this, though.

Comment: @Ansgar - I'm fairly new using an ETL Tool call Pervasive n I have been tryin to convert XML to ascii del format. The ETL software reads each xml node as a "RecordName". So when I am converting my data n tryin to create a row for each record, it is creating n additional row for recordname that are the same. So to solve my problem, I attempted to write a script to either add a node where exist 1 node of <HolderAccount> and rename to HolderAccount1 and the new node HolderAccount2. For nodes where exist two <HolderAccount>, rename both. This is all new to me and just trying to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the code a bit to better suit your logic.  It looks like you've changed your specifications to enumerate the first node as well, so we can get rid of the `If` statement altogether.  Your `Else` block was always being called since `count_var` always started at one for each `HolderAccounts` container.

Instead, we only want to handle the case where there is one account under a node.  The inner most loop will copy it, but we need to add the new, empty `HolderAccount` node as well.

**Input**

```xml
<FabeDole>
    <HolderAccounts>
        <HolderAccount>test</HolderAccount>
    </HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccounts>
        <HolderAccount>test</HolderAccount>
        <HolderAccount>test</HolderAccount>
    </HolderAccounts>
</FabeDole>
```

**Output**

```xml
<FabeDole>
    <HolderAccounts>
        <HolderAccount1>test</HolderAccount1>
        <HolderAccount2/>
    </HolderAccounts>
    <HolderAccounts>
        <HolderAccount1>test</HolderAccount1>
        <HolderAccount2>test</HolderAccount2>
    </HolderAccounts>
</FabeDole>
```

**Code**

```vbs
Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.async = False
count_var = 1

If xml.Load("C:\XML_DATA2.xml") Then
    For Each HolderAccounts In xml.SelectNodes("//HolderAccounts")
        Set HolderAccountCollection = HolderAccounts.SelectNodes("./HolderAccount")

        For Each HolderAccount In HolderAccountCollection

            Set accountEnum = xml.createNode(1, "HolderAccount" & count_var, "")
            For Each child In HolderAccount.childNodes
                accountEnum.appendChild(child.cloneNode(True))
            Next
            HolderAccounts.replaceChild accountEnum, HolderAccount

            count_var = count_var + 1
        Next

        If HolderAccountCollection.Length = 1 Then HolderAccounts.appendChild(xml.createNode(1,"HolderAccount" & count_var,""))
        count_var = 1   
    Next
    xml.Save("C:\XML_DATA2.xml")
End If
```

Comment: @FabeDole : no problem, glad I can help.  Had to edit around the code a bit, & I added a small explanation that may help you understand why your code was creating an extra `HolderAccount2`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That definitely solved my issue. What took me several hours of reading and playing around (and still getting it wrong) took you a minute,. Great weekend to you!